# Make class module in a MSWord vba project apply only to the document it was created in

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a class module in a vba project that I want to apply only to the document it was created in. For some reason it applies to all open MSWord documents, as long as the document containing the class module is open. I am using MS Word in Office 2013.

To clarify: I work as a private language tutor. For each student, I keep a record of work and hours worked in a separate MSWord document. I have a class module in the 'record of work' document that flashes up a reminder to update my notes when i try to close the document. Unfortunately, as long as the 'record of work' document is open, the same reminder flashes up whenever i try to close any other MSWord docs.

I have tried a couple of solutions, including most recently using "Option Private Module", but get an error message as, apparently, Object modules have the characteristic of Option Private Module by default.

I'm guessing this is quite a simple problem to fix, if you know what you are doing. Unfortunately, I don't. I have no programming experience, but am willing to make the effort to understand any advice posted in response to this request. Pasting in a couple of screen shots below:

[reminder to update before close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCxmS.jpg)

The current code is as follows:

```
Option Explicit 
Public WithEvents oApp As Word.Application 

Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean) 
Dim response As Integer 
response = MsgBox("Updated Record of Work?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) 
If response <> vbYes Then 
  Cancel = True 
  MsgBox "Update and then close again." 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Visible in the screen shot link above, but here's the module text:

Option Explicit
Public WithEvents oApp As Word.Application
Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim response As Integer
    response = MsgBox("Updated Record of Work?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
     
    If response <> vbYes Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Update and then close again."
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Event your code responds to is an Application Event, so it *will* be fired whenever any document opened in the application is closed.

If you change your code to the following, the Sub will still be called whenever a document is closed, but the message box will only be displayed if the document is the one that contains the code:

```
Option Explicit 
Public WithEvents oApp As Word.Application 

Private Sub oApp_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As Boolean) 
Dim response As Integer 
If Doc = ThisDocument Then
  response = MsgBox("Updated Record of Work?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) 
  If response <> vbYes Then 
    Cancel = True 
    MsgBox "Update and then close again." 
  End If
End If 
End Sub
```